# Counting items on one model and writing results to another model on Django

Tags: django, model, count

```
class ModelOne (models.Model):
    manufacturer        = models.CharField (max_length=50, unique=True)
    number_of_models    = models.IntegerField () 

class ModelTwo (models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey (ModelOne)
    model_name  = models.CharField (max_length=50)
```

What i need to do is,

Count every *model_name* in **ModelTwo** for each *manufacturer*, and write to **ModelOne** as *number_of_models* for each *manufacturer* in admin.py

Thank you for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) for counting names:

```
from django.db.models import Count
manufacters = ModelTwo.objects.values('manufacturer').annotate(count=Count('model_name'))
```

It return dict with manufacters and number of model_name for each manufacter and then you can save it in your ModelOne using create or [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method